# What does a dash represents in CURRENT-OFFSET

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Referring below screenshot of consumer-group description, i am trying to understand what does "-" means here for CURRENT-OFFSET. Does it says that messages are not consumed from partition 1 & 3 even though the partitions are allocated to a consumer. LOG-END offset for partition 1 & 3 are 281 & 277 respectively .

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`CURRENT-OFFSET` means the current max offset of the consumed messages of the partition for this consumer instance, whereas `LOG-END-OFFSET` is the offset of the latest message in the partition.

In your case, consumers have already consumed all the messages for partition 0 and 2, that's why the lags for those two partitions are zero. However, for partition 1 and 3, either there were no consumer instances assigned to them or consumers failed to read any records for those two partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Partitions 1 and 3 are not reporting the `current-offset` and the `lag` because no Kafka commits are done for them. That can be the case even if consumer instances are assigned to them that are reading records.

Comment: How can that happen ??

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me.  The offset should still be numeric.  Otherwise there is an undefined offset.  Even if there are no commits - there has to be a current offset.  No?

Comment: @vkamenen, I had similar issue as I was not committing offset to kafka topic's partition. The reason I dint want to commit is due to a code issue while processing Kafka message. And upon next poll, kafka does not get the messages from offset record but gets it from the last processed offset.
How can we poll the same message from offset record for processing the same record after the bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. In my case, there were 2 consumers, running under the same consumer group. One consumer was running in the dev environment and another consumer was running in my local.

The instance of the consumer running in my local latched itself to one of the partitions but it couldn't read any messages from that partition. As a result of that, the lag count kept increasing. My local had some issue with Read rights and hence couldn't process the messages.

So just because your consumer latches itself with a partition, it doesn't mean that it can read records.